# Can I write a dynamic tree structure in C++?

Tags: c++, dynamic, tree

I need a tree with n branches in C++, What is the best way to code this? Or where can I find a implementation?

Comment: What do you need it for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This](http://tree.phi-sci.com/) is one option, [this](http://stlplus.sourceforge.net/stlplus/docs/ntree.html) is another, and finally [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/graph/doc/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Found a similar implementation here:[enter link description here](http://tree.phi-sci.com/)